# Feedme CSV into Redactor encoded as JSON

Tags: redactor, plugin-feedme, csv

Importing into Redactor from a CSV file and we have no control over the formatting.
There is a column containing text that is in quote marks but on importing into a Redactor field, any string that contains a comma is treated as a JSON object, so eg:

```
"Our used vans also come with free MobiloVan roadside assistance, meaning you will not need to pay any additional costs for breakdown cover. As the UK’s largest Mercedes-Benz commercial vehicle franchise Dealer in the UK, Rygor is well positioned to offer extensive expertise and support."
```

Is being saved as:

[image: screenshot from CMS]

How best to save this as a paragraph within Redactor without FeedMe thinking it is a JSON object or interpreting the commas within the string as delimiters?

Craft v 3.6.16
FeedMe v 4.3.6

Cole

Comment: What’s the entire row of the CSV file you’re having issues with? How is the original CSV being output? My guess is it’s not being escaped properly.

Comment: Thanks @RitterKnight - sample row posted at https://gist.github.com/cole007/86214342b1e3f0a853afb84c04dd26b3

Sample output (in Redactor) come out as:

```
["Our used vans also come with free MobiloVan roadside assistance","meaning you will not need to pay any additional costs for breakdown cover. As the UK\u2019s largest Mercedes-Benz commercial vehicle franchise Dealer in the UK","Rygor is well positioned to offer extensive expertise and support."]
```

Comment: Very odd. I grabbed your CSV and popped it into my test Craft install and it worked fine. Are you changing any settings in the [``feedme config``](https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/get-started/configuration.html#control-panel)? I had no problems importing. I ran you CSV sample through an [online linter](https://csvlint.io) and it mentioned "Your CSV appears to be encoded in ASCII-8BIT. We recommend you use UTF-8"  but that didn't affect my import. some servers might have issues with that though, which could also explain the ``\u2019`` in place of the apostrophe...

Comment: Some progress on this (at least in looking at the source of the issue).
It seems to be only affecting Redactor fields within a Matrix Block.

Imagine changing the datadelimiter setting would resolve but we are tied to the formatting of the file supplied (and its formatting) in this instance.

Comment: Your original question didn't mention Matrix blocks at all but I wasn't able to reproduce your problem. Importing into a matrix text block worked just fine on a stock install for me. Must be something with your config?